# Using web3j with infura returns null

Tags: web3j, infura, error, android

I've used web3.js to handle my contracts, and it worked very well.

But web3j is pretty hard for me since the beginning.

I'm using android studio, infura, web3j.
Since I don't know very much about web3j, I can't explain more.

Following is my code:

```
Web3j web3 = Web3jFactory.build(new HttpService("http://kovan.infura.io/v3/4eae1227d0544298b86b29de0b5cf048"));
    Log.d("MYDEBUG | web3","web3 build complete");

    Web3ClientVersion web3ClientVersion = null;

    try {
        web3ClientVersion = web3.web3ClientVersion().send();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(NetworkOnMainThreadException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(web3ClientVersion != null) {
        String web3ClientVersionString = web3ClientVersion.getWeb3ClientVersion();
        if (web3ClientVersionString == null) {
            Log.d("MYDEBUG | web3j version ", "NULL");
        } else {
            Log.d("MYDEBUG | web3j version", web3ClientVersionString);
        }
    }
    else{
        Log.d("MYDEBUG | web3ClientVersion ", "NULL");
    }
```

Since the very beginning of the project, building web3j fails.

When I run this code, web3ClientVersion always returns null. I can't figure out what went wrong.
http://kovan.infura.io/v3/4eae1227d0544298b86b29de0b5cf048 is my infura project endpoint.

The error is below.

`W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1448)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:171)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:137)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:82)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:171)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
at org.web3j.protocol.http.HttpService.performIO(HttpService.java:110)
at org.web3j.protocol.Service.send(Service.java:32)
at org.web3j.protocol.core.Request.send(Request.java:72)
at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.getBalance(MainActivity.java:133)
at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:82)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897)
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12693)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26104)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)`

Comment: @Ismael you meant `https` instead of `http`:D

Comment: @Div You are correct. Try with `https` instead of `http` I think secure connection are required now.